# Visual Studio 2015 no longer generates executable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build, executable

I had a Windows Forms application that needed some UI and code changes changes made to it. I made the proper changes (mainly deleting a few controls and moving some code). Oddly after the changes were made, I would rebuild run, and despite the changes, the changes being saved, and builds being made multiple times,the application would always run as if the changes were never made.

I tried to *Build -> Clean Solution* a few times, with no avail. I decided to try manually deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuild. However, after closing the solution, deleting those folders, I tried to build again and get the following error:

[image]

OutputPath and AssemblyName are set correctly as far as I'm aware. This only affects Debug, Release runs fine (sort of) and even in debug XML and `*.vshost` files are created, but not the executable. I've tried restarting VS a few times to no avail. What in the world did I do and how do I fix it?

**EDIT** After right clicking on the solution and doing a batch-build on *all* projects in the solution, things started working. I still have no idea what happened, so if anyone has any theories feel free to comment.

Comment: This is not a build error.  You are trying to *run* the program.  It isn't there.  Check the Error List.  Disable the installed anti-malware product next.

Comment: @HansPassant I ended up figuring out, but it still normally builds first when clicking start, there was nothing in the error list.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Output window provide any details about where the .exe was created?

You may need to increase the verbosity of the logging. To do so, go to the Options dialog (Tools > Options) and open "Projects and Solutions" > "Build and Run."  Change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" and recompile.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything useful in the log, however, I right-clicked on the solution and did a batch-build on *all* projects and it's working again. No idea what happened :/